# How did Ron get the Basilisk fang if Voldemort already destroyed it?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), Voldemort is shown destroying a Basilisk fang:

[image: Animated GIF of Voldemort destroying the fang]

In the next scene, Ron is shown holding a Basilisk fang:

[image: Ron holding the Basilisk fang]

How did Ron get the Basilisk fang if Voldemort already destroyed it?

Comment: Is it not possible that there was more than one Basilisk fang? Creatures with fangs tend to have multiple fangs, not just one.

Comment: @F1Krazy Or for that matter more than one *Basilisk* - it'd be pretty strange if the one under Hogwarts is the last of its species...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman As far as we know, basilisks don't reproduce: "This snake, which may reach gigantic size, and live many hundreds of years, is born from a chicken's egg, hatched beneath a toad."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the books (though perhaps not shown in the movies) Ron and Hermione retrieve multiple fangs from the Chamber of Secrets:

> And then he skidded around a final corner and with a yell of mingled relief
> and fury he saw them: Ron and Hermione; both with their arms full of large,
> curved, dirty yellow objects, Ron with a broomstick under his arms.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter Thirty-One - The Battle of Hogwarts</sub>

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3nmx7NWzLc Not sure of the scene order to what the OP is asking about though, been a while since I've watched it.

Comment: Now that I read that passage again it strikes me as incredibly stupid to have your arms full of basilisk fangs given how sharp and poisonous they are. I would think a bag might have been a wiser choice

Comment: IIRC it gets mentioned in the book that they ripped the teeth out of the skull of the basilisk skeleton? So that single tooth being destroyed wouldn't have mattered anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: That is just one of many incredibly stupid things, which is why people have to read HP with both eyes shut if they don't want their heads to burst.

Comment: @Kevin: I agree it's stupid, but then again we are talking about 12 years old kids barely hanging on. I'd argue it's the same kind of stupid as people in zombie movies, except that the recent pandemic has shown and again that yes, people actually do that... because

Comment: I wouldn't count this as an answer because the books aren't the movies. If the movie only showed one fang and then it was destroyed then I would call that a plot hole. Do you have a scene from the movie to explain?

Comment: @MatthieuM. they are 17 at this point

Comment: @rtaft you say that as though the average 17 year old thinks coherently and plans accordingly...

Comment: @FreeMan I would like to think that when I was 17 and I needed to carry a dozen or two knives, that in the back of my mind I would have a sense that the pointy end should face away from me, but not quite enough sense to think that if I'm cutting something to not put my finger on the other side.

Comment: @Kevin - Where are they said to be *sharp*, actually?

Comment: @Malady I would say that the fact that they are fangs that are specifically there to puncture skin to inject poison would suggest that they are fairly sharp. Also if they were totally blunt then I don't see how they would be much use in destroying horcruxes

Answer (score 6):

In the movie, you can assume that Ron and Hermione retrieve multiple fangs, and then one or more is destroyed while they attempt to eliminate Nagini.

None of this happens in the books. There is never a sequence of Nagini fighting Ron, Hermione, or any of the other students or relevant characters. What you see in the movie for dramatic effect offers Voldemort more interactive participation in the fight and raises the tension and stakes as Nagini develops into a threatening force with only two known weakness.

Voldemort keeps the snake safe and quite out of reach for the majority of the fight for protection. In the book, Ron and Hermione go to the basilisk fangs, retrieve some, vanquishing the cup Horcrux. They then held onto extra fangs for several chapters, but never got a chance to use them on any other Horcrux:

- the diadem is destroyed by Crabbe's fire (rendering the fangs moot)
- Nagini is held out of reach for 90%, and the last 10% carried carelessly cut by the Sword of Gryffindor (in an opportunist move from Neville, when Voldemort drops his protection)

I don't think Hermione or Ron ever get a chance to even try to use the excess fangs on either. It was a default contingency to have multiple so that there wasn't a single point of failure; however, they ended up being extraneous / redundant.

***Multiple fangs***:

> Harry’s eyes dropped to the objects clutched in Ron and Hermione’s arms: great
> curved fangs; torn, he now realized, from the skull of a dead basilisk.
>
> “But how did you get in there?” he asked, staring from the fangs to Ron. “You
> need to speak Parseltongue!”
>
> Chapter 31, The Battle of Hogwarts

This dialogue occurs during the evacuation and fortification stage before the fight.

***Destruction of Hufflepuff cup***:

> “So we’re another Horcrux down,” said Ron, and from under his jacket he pulled
> the mangled remains of Hufflepuff’s cup. “Hermione stabbed it. Thought she should. She hasn’t had the pleasure yet.”
>
> Chapter 31, The Battle of Hogwarts

So it was destroyed by a fang "off-screen". Same discussion as the other quote before.

***Lost diadem***:

> He pulled the diadem from his wrist and held it up. It was still hot, blackened with soot...
>
> A bloodlike substance, dark and tarry, seemed to be leaking from the diadem.
> Suddenly Harry felt the thing vibrate violently, then break apart in his hands...
>
> “It must have been Fiendfyre!” whimpered Hermione, her eyes on the broken
> piece.
>
> “Sorry?”
>
> “Fiendfyre – cursed fire – it’s one of the substances that destroy Horcruxes, but I would never, ever have dared use it, it’s so dangerous – how did Crabbe know how to – ?”
>
> Chapter 31, The Battle of Hogwarts

This occurs directly after Harry, Draco, Ron, Hermione, and Goyle escape the room where the diadem is hidden. Crabbe released Fiendfyre, incapable to control it, and it consumes him and also damages the diadem enough to burn the item to ash. No basilisk fang necessary. At this point, the battle is in full progress, and Nagini does not participate.

***Publicizing that the snake needs to be targeted***:

> "You know Voldemort’s snake. Neville? He’s got a huge snake . . .
> Calls it Nagini . . .”
>
> “I’ve heard, yeah . . . What about it?”
>
> “It’s got to be killed. Ron and Hermione know that, but just in case they ---“
> he pulled himself together again: This was crucial, he must be like
> Dumbledore, keep a cool head, make sure there were backups, others to carry on.
> Dumbledore had died knowing that three people still knew about the Horcruxes; now
> Neville would take Harry’s place: There would still be three in the secret.
>
> “Just in case they’re --- busy --- and you get the chance ---“
>
> “Kill the snake?”
>
> “Kill the snake,” Harry repeated.
>
> “All right, Harry. You’re okay, are you?”
>
> Chapter 34, The Forest (Again)

Neville is made a contingency, and ends up being what's needed rather than the basilisk fangs.

***Voldemort projecting a spell that secures the snake***:

> ...the snake, coiling and uncoiling in the glittering cage behind Voldemort’s head.
>
> Although Harry could feel his wand, he made no attempt to draw it. He
> knew that the snake was too well protected, knew that if he managed to point the wand at Nagini, fifty curses would hit him first. And still, Voldemort and Harry looked at each other, and now Voldemort tilted his head a little to the side, considering the boy standing before him, and a singularly mirthless smile curled the lipless mouth.
>
> Chapter 34, The Forest (Again)

Harry surrenders knowing that he is a Horcrux that must die, upon seeing past discussion by Dumbledore; Voldemort not only keeps Nagini away from the battle, he also keeps it behind a protective magic barrier in the presence of dozens of followers. These multiple precautions cause a direct attempt with a fang difficult, perhaps intractable. He hopes that Hermione and Ron will find a way to get close somehow.

***Nagini unprotected; Voldemort's hubris***:

> "Come," said Voldemort, and Harry heard him move ahead, and Hagrid was
> forced to follow. Now Harry opened his eyes a fraction, and saw Voldemort striding in front them, wearing the great snake Nagini around his shoulders, now free of her enchanted cage. But Harry had no possibility of extracting the wand concealed under his robes without being noticed by the Death Eaters, who marched on the either side of them through the slowly lightening darkness.
>
> Chapter 36, Flaw in the Plan

Here, we see Voldemort becoming overconfident because he thinks Harry is dead, and he's already painted him as a deserter in order to crush the remaining dissenters' spirits. So he's dropped the protective spell placed on Nagini, unaware that Harry is observing these actions.

> He squinted again for a single second and saw the open doorway filling with people, as the survivors of the battle came out onto the front steps
> to face their vanquishers and see the truth of Harry's death for themselves. He saw Voldemort standing a little in front of him, stroking Nagini's head
> with a single white finger.

He can't help it, needing to vaunt Harry's downfall. Nagini again shown to be vulnerable.

***Distractions, and something about pulling swords out of a hat***:

> Screams split the dawn, and Neville was aflame, rooted to the spot, unable to
> move, and Harry could not bear it: He must act -
> And then many things happened at the same moment.
>
> They heard uproar from the distant boundary of the school as what sounded like
> hundreds of people came swarming over the out-of-sight walls and pelted toward the
> castle, uttering loud war cries. At the same time, Grawp came lumbering around the side
> of the castle and yelled, "HAGGER!" His cry was answered by roars from Voldemort's
> giants: they ran at Grawp like bull elephants making the earth quake. Then came hooves
> and the twangs of bows, and arrows were suddenly falling amongst the Death Eaters, who
> broke ranks, shouting their surprise. Harry pulled the Invisibilty Cloak from inside his
> robes, swung it over himself, and sprang to his feet, as Neville moved too.
>
> In one swift, fluid motion, Neville broke free of the Body-Bind Curse upon him;
> the flaming hat fell off him and he drew from its depths something silver, with a
> glittering, rubied handle -
>
> The slash of the silver blade could not be heard over the roar of the oncoming
> crowd or the sounds of the clashing giants or of the stampeding centaurs, and yet, it seemed to draw every eye. With a single stroke Neville sliced off the great snake's head.
>
> Chapter 36, Flaw in the Plan

Various factors played a part in Nagini's decapitation, including arrogance, showmanship, distraction, luck, timeliness, and bravery. The extra fangs didn't factor into the final outcome; however, their existence provided direction and a basis for the Horcrux destruction in the event that nothing else were to congeal, and the character decision-making partially relied on their effectiveness as a preferred method.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing fangs. The one destroyed by Voldemort was given to Harry by Ron. It was destroyed during Harry's fight with Voldemort, when Harry attempted at killing Nagini with it.

Ron holds, in next scene, a different fang. As mentioned in other answer, Ron and Hermione retrieved several fangs from The Chamber of Secrets, and distributed them among the three of them.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie Ron and Hermione go down to retrieve more basilisk fangs from the Chamber of Secrets which is why they are absent for a bit before the second scene.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! If you could put sources (screenshots, book or movie quotes, etc) in your answer, it would greatly improve the credibility.